# ANT deployment error in Communities?

Tags: community, deployment, mdapideploy

I have a partner community which had a 'New Lead' link on community header which opened up Lead list view. 
Now i have changed it to open a community page. When i deploy this change set using ANT to UAT or any other environment i get the following error.

```
1.  networks/Partner Community.network -- Error: The default listview AllOpenLeads is not associated with entity /leadsub
```

Comment: Did you include the community page in your change set?

Comment: yes i did, but now i have found out the solution. Our repo was picking up <defaultlistview> tag inspite it not being sObject type tab.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Nav from the deploy, send the new page over, then send the Nav on the next deploy.